# PHImageResultIsDegradedKey/PHImageFileURLKey is not found

Tags: ios, phasset, photokit, ios13, phimagemanager

iOS 13 beta4 no longer gives

1) PHImageFileURLKey 
2) PHImageResultIsDegradedKey in image result info keys.

Anyone knows a way to find the fileurl of the PHAsset?

Comment: Any luck with 'PHImageResultIsDegradedKey'?

Comment: I don't think it will be available further on as iOS 13 nears its public release :( @AravindMariappan

Comment: But nothing is mentioned about it's depreciation in the documentation. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phimageresultisdegradedkey?language=objc

Comment: hello i am also facing the same issue. Any luck in this ?

Comment: @ChaudharyAnkitDeshwal Please look into the answers posted. Hope it will solve the problem.

Comment: Please have a look at the "localIdentifier" property of PHObject which can use instead "PHImageFileURLKey" https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photokit/phobject/1622400-localidentifier

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.**PHImageResultIsDegradedKey** is now being available in latest iOS 13 GM and GM2. So one problem solved.

2.**PHImageFileURLKey** won't be available in iOS 13 and if you are in so need of fileURL of an image asset and you need it without any PhotoKit's methods callback go for regex in description of asset. It will work.

You can get the `description` of a PHAssetResource object using **+[PHAssetResource assetResourcesForAsset:]** , use first object from resulting array and then extract the `fileURL` from string using regex:

```
public static func getFileURLFromPHAssetResourceDescription(description: String) -> String? {
    let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<=fileURL: ).*(?=\\s)")
    if let result = regex.firstMatch(in: description, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: description.count)) {
        let url = String(description[Range(result.range, in: description)!])
        return url
    }
    return nil
}
```

Note: Only available from iOS9

Comment: Why use the first object from `PHAssetResource assetResourcesForAsset:]` result?

Comment: It's upto your choice to go with original content or edited content(if any) @Giorgio

Comment: In iOS13, from my test, in first position you don't find always the original content. For example, for an edited image, I find a .plist file.

Comment: Please have a look at the localIdentifier property of PHObject. it is also can be used.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use this function from PHAsset object:

```
- (PHContentEditingInputRequestID)requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:(nullable PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *)options completionHandler:(void (^)(PHContentEditingInput *__nullable contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info))completionHandler;
```

Then you can retrieve URL this way:

```
NSURL *url = contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL;
```

Answer (score 2):

Some example Objective-C code for anyone else looking for it:

```
PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions *editOptions = [[PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions alloc] init];

[myPHAsset requestContentEditingInputWithOptions:editOptions completionHandler:^(PHContentEditingInput *contentEditingInput, NSDictionary *info) {

    if (contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL) {
        //do something with contentEditingInput.fullSizeImageURL
    }

}];
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is looking to achieve the same on Xamarin.iOS, this is my C# version of the swift code:

```
phAsset.RequestContentEditingInput(new PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions(), phcontentediting);
```

and then:

```
private void phcontentediting(PHContentEditingInput contentEditingInput, NSDictionary requestStatusInfo)
        {

        }
```

when `phcontentediting` is called, contentEditingInput has a lot of useful information such as `CreationDate`, `FullSizeImageUrl` and even `Location`!

Comment: Make sure to call contentEditingInput.Dispose(); or the app will crash when called with many photos.

Answer (score 1):

let resourse = PHAssetResource.assetResources(for: self.phasset)

let url = resourse.first?.originalFilename

This works for me ！

Comment: please provide some explanation

Comment: Sorry, this method is just to fetch the file name not url

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion of guhan0, I made a small change. Indeed, sometimes, there are more than 1 "fileURL:...", so, I take the first when the value start with "file://" which means there is a file url. I think there is a better solution, but for now, it works well:

```
private func getFileURLFromPHAssetResource(resourceDescription description: String) -> String? {

        let regex = try! NSRegularExpression(pattern: "(?<=fileURL: ).*(?=\\s)")

        for match in regex.matches(in: description, options: [], range: NSRange(location: 0, length: description.count)).lazy {

            let url = String(description[Range(match.range, in: description)!])

            if url.starts(with: "file://") { return url }
        }

        return nil
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In iOS 13.0, **PHImageFileURLKey** is removed. In order to access PHAsset data, When we call this function to requestImageData we can get image information through this key **PHImageFileUTIKey**.

```
PHImageManager.default().requestImageData(for: asset, options: PHImageRequestOptions(), resultHandler:{ [weak self] (imagedata, dataUTI, orientation, info) in

if let assetInfo = info, let fileURLKey = assetInfo["PHImageFileUTIKey"] as? NSString {
let fileComp = fileURLKey.components(separatedBy: ".")

if fileComp.count > 0 {
   // Do your stuff.
}

})
```

Comment: the PHImageFileUTIKey is not a replacement for PHImageFileURLKey, there is no correlation between them, what's the point of having the value of PHImageFileUTIKey then?

Answer (score 0):

If anyone needs the file size when using RequestContentEditingInput in Xamarin.

```
var options = new PHContentEditingInputRequestOptions();
asset.RequestContentEditingInput(options, (PHContentEditingInput contentEditingInput, NSDictionary requestStatusInfo) =>
{
    var imageUrl = contentEditingInput.FullSizeImageUrl.ToString();

    NSObject fileSizeObj;
    if (contentEditingInput.FullSizeImageUrl.TryGetResource(new NSString("NSURLFileSizeKey"), out fileSizeObj))
    {
        var fileSizeNSNum = fileSizeObj as NSNumber;
        long fileSize = fileSizeNSNum.Int64Value;
    }

    // Make sure to dispose or your app will crash with a lot of photos!
    contentEditingInput.Dispose();

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
let photoPath = photoAsset.localIdentifier
```

to replace the

```
let photoPath = info["PHImageFileURLKey"]
```